# Matrix finding $A=SDS^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$\displaystyle A= \begin{bmatrix}-18 & 10 \\ -20 & 12 \end{bmatrix}$

Find $S$, $D$, $S^{-1}$ such that $A = SDS^{-1}$

I used eigenvalues for $D$ and eigenvectors for $S$ but not getting right answer.

Comment: Well, for a first start, what eigenvalues did you get?

Answer (score 1):

So our matrix is:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}-18 & 10 \\ -20 & 12 \end{bmatrix}$$

Now, we can can find the eigenvalues by setting us our matrix:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}-18-\lambda & 10 \\ -20 & 12 - \lambda \end{bmatrix} = (-18-\lambda)(12-\lambda) + 200 = -216 + 6\lambda + \lambda^2 + 200 = 0\\ -16 + 6\lambda + \lambda^2 = 0,\ (\lambda +8)(\lambda -2) = 0$$

Therefore, our eigenvalues are $\lambda = 2, -8$

Now, substitute this back in to the matrix to find your corresponding eigenvectors.

After this, our diagonalizable matrix D is spanned by the column vectors that correspond to your eigenvectors.

Comment: thanks just had some calculation error